# How to run php with postgres?

Tags: php, postgresql

How do i use postgresql with kali / fedodra? I've tried doing it but php doesn't connect to postgresql. I even changed the php.ini file and enables the extension. but still doesn't work. Can anyone tell me the full process to do all the necessary installations and run my php code with postgresql.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ref.pdo-pgsql.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `php-pgsql` in Fedora in addition to the `postgresql-server` package.

Assuming that you already have PHP and Apache configured:

```
$ sudo dnf install postgresql-server
$ sudo dnf install php-pgsql
```

You might need to run the following before using postgresql-server

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/postgresql-setup --initdb
```